# Visual Studio 2008 remote debugging disabled? (no "Remote" transport)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

has anyone seen this happen before?  I need to do remote debugging but don't seem to have the option to use it.  When I load Visual Studio 2008 and go into the **Tools > Attach to Process** menu, the only Transport that is listed (first dropdown) is "Default".  That means that I can't switch to the "Remote (Native Only)" transport I would use to do remote debugging.

Am I missing some permissions? Does my version not support remote debugging? I've spent an hour searching Google for any reason why it might not appear......

My version info:
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
- Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1
- Installed Edition: Standard

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote debugging is only available on the Pro and Team version of Visual Studio 2008.
More info here [Remote debugging Setup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: damn, introducing artificial licensing differences really sucks.  I have a full MSDN subscription, but I guess I picked the wrong version to install.  Thanks for the answer!